# Adding support libraries v7, v13 with gradle is not working

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to import both android support libraries. I'm trying to implent GoogleMaps AP2 into my Android Application. Therefore I need both libraries. I'm using AndroidStudio and Gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:18.0.+"
    compile "com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile "com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+"
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.5'
}
```

The error is:

```
Module version com.android.support:support-v13:18.0.0 depends on libraries but is not a library itself
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to use the latest version of support-v13:21.0.+

You have this error because both appcompat and support-v13 depends on support-v4 and their is a version conflict.

Not the best error by the way.

Comment: Okay, I get that. And how can I fix this problem? Is there no way to compile both?

Comment: Just replace the version of support-v13 for `compile "com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+"`

Answer (score 3):

Finally this code is working for me in:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile "com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile "com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+"
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.5'
}
```

Comment: Now , please use `compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.+"`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and found https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73802: '*The support-v13:19.1.0 library has incorrect metadata, probably resulting from the switch to AAR from JAR*'

I tried building with a bunch of different combinations and found the following:

1) If using support-v13 < support-v13:20.0.0, all other support libraries must also be before 20.0.0

2) If using support-v13 >= support-v13:20.0.0, other support libraries can be any version.

Example:

**support-v13 < support-v13:20.0.0 with other support libs >= 20.0.0**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.0'
```

*Error:Module version com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.0 depends on libraries but is not a library itself*

**support-v13 < support-v13:20.0.0 with other support libs < 20.0.0**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.0'
```

*Builds fine*

**support-v13 >= support-v13:20.0.0**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
```

*Builds fine*

So, just make sure support-v13 is at least support-v13:20.0.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'`

Answer (score 0):

For v13 add compileSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 21, and compile "com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+"
You may not comment line 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3', this should work
My gradle sample

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "someId"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+"
```

}